# <o:massAttribute> affects another components in same <h:panelGrid>

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I'm using the new version of [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) 1.8.1, and particullary I start to use the new tag: [`<o:massAttribute>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute). Basically, I have the following form with conditionally rendered and disabled fields:

```
<h:form id="formABMProducto">
    <h:panelGrid id="datosProducto" columns="4">
        <o:massAttribute name="rendered" value="#{cc.attrs.page != 'baja'}">
            <h:outputLabel for="codigo" ... />
            <h:inputText id="codigo" ... />
            <rich:message for="codigo" />
            <h:panelGroup />
        </o:massAttribute>

        <o:massAttribute name="rendered" value="#{cc.attrs.page eq 'baja'}">
            <h:outputLabel for="codigo" .../>
            <rich:autocomplete id="codigoProducto" ... />
            <rich:message for="codigo" />
            <h:panelGroup />                    
        </o:massAttribute>

        <o:massAttribute name="disabled" value="#{cc.attrs.disableComponents}">
            <h:outputLabel for="nombre" ... />
            <h:inputTextarea id="nombre" ... />     
            <rich:message for="nombre" />
            <span />

            <h:outputLabel for="descripcion" ... />
            <h:inputTextarea id="descripcion" ... />    
            <rich:message for="descripcion" />
            <span />
        </o:massAttribute>

        <h:outputLabel value="#{msgs['producto.abm.panel.proveedor.tipo']}" for="CmbTipoProveedor"/>
        <rich:select id="CmbTipoProveedor" ... />
        <rich:message for="CmbTipoProveedor" />
        <a4j:commandButton ... />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

However, when I open the page, the third `<o:massAttribute>` is *also* disabling another input fields `codigo` and `codigoProducto`. I think this isn't the expected behaviour.

Comment: This is inside a composite component, right? Is it in turn inside a `<h:dataTable>` or `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:panelGrid>`? In any way, a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help a lot to quickly nailing down the problem.

Comment: yes is inside the composite:implementation, and h:panelGrid. i edit the code above for you can see the page. i will try to remove the components outside h:panelGrid, maybe is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this was a bug. The `<o:massAttribute>` got applied on all children of the parent `UIComponent` instead of only those contained in the tag. It would theoretically have worked when you've wrapped each `<o:massAttribute>` in its own `UIComponent` like `<h:panelGroup>` or so. However, this is clearly not an option in case of a `<h:panelGrid>` wherein you'd like to put the children each in its own column.

I reproduced your problem, filled [issue 51](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/51) about this bug and [fixed it](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/796b950524eeac2af967f2a7fda15cd3b2f2e09b) in the [current 2.0 snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.0-SNAPSHOT/). Please give it a try and sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: No problem thanks for the help and the quick answer in my particular case i fixed putting disabled in false in the component that i need(the autocomplete component) to be enabled, but i will try your solution. You have a great library help me in many complicated things in jsf, thanks for the contribution. I think i find a bug in the <o:highlight /> too i will add in another questions for you.

Comment: You're welcome. If you're confident of a bug, please report it at https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues instead.

Comment: Finally was a bug in my code in the <o:highlight /> is working fine thanks.